# Is this character being impersonated?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

At the end of *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, Drowned Logan is retrieved from the river by Stryker and a rescue crew.

We see Stryker's eyes shift colour, but not to the red/yellow of Mystique.

**Who is this?  Is this person a mutant, or is someone else impersonating him?**

Comment: Do you have a screenshot, because I specifically remember them flashing yellow, the same as Mystique's

Comment: I remember the eyes flashing like Mystique's, too, are you sure you saw the color right OP?

Comment: I don't have a screen shot. Saw it last night in 3D and was focusing on the face and it didn't look like Nystique"s eyes.

Comment: I'm still looking for a screenshot or something official from someone involved with the production, but *every* article I'm finding agrees that it's Mystique impersonating Stryker.

Comment: edited for spoilers. feel free to rollback or integrate differently.

Comment: Now I'm hoping it *wasn't* Mystique. It would be pretty cool if it turned out movieverse Wolverine got his adamantium from Apocalypse...

Comment: @phantom42 if it is Mystique, why is she rescuing Wolverine? There are no references of Wolverine known to Mystique by 1973.

Comment: @arunborn2win41 Mystique likely knew about him originally from when Xavier and Erik attempted to recruit him for the First Class. Wolverine was also one of the group that tried to stop her in Paris and she watched him and Erik fight in the stadium. Additionally, it seems she had been looking into locations of mutants (she knew about the ones in the military and had presumably been looking for info on ones captured by Trask) and may have come across info on him during her other espionage.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The color is off in the 3D version. It is indeed Mystique rescuing Logan by pretending to be Stryker.

Comment: I saw the 3d version and came to the conclusion you've stated (convoluted phrasing to avoid mentioning the spoiler).

Answer (score 12):

"Stryker's" eyes clearly flash yellow - the same as Mystique's in previous films, and even *Days of Future Past*.

[image: mutants in disguise!]

[image: surprise, I'm really Mystique!]

In [this interview](http://collider.com/simon-kinberg-x-men-apocalypse/), Simon Kinberg 100% confirms that it is Mystique impersonating Stryker.

> *Stryker is a character that keeps reappearing in the franchise, perhaps because he’s one of the only identifiable bad guys the X-Men have encountered. And then, in the final beats of the film, it turns out he’s Mystique — the ultimate “WTF.” Will that payoff in the future?*
>
> We really wanted to do something subtle with Stryker in this movie. We wanted it to be the beginning of the origin of him. He’s in the shadows most of this film. In some ways, Stryker was included in order to trigger something for Wolverine. How would it impact Wolverine, going back in time and seeing this guy who is going to manipulate him in the future. That was just interesting. Stryker’s been interesting in the books and the Brian Cox version was fantastic. **But the last moment in the movie with the Mystique reveal… there’s for sure more to that.** As we follow the characters in to X-Men: Apocalypse, we have to address that and make it a real thing.

Answer (score 6):

The film's director, Simon Kinsberg has [explicitly confirmed](http://www.empireonline.com/features/days-of-future-past-secrets-explained/p6) that it's Mystique at the end, impersonating Stryer;

> ***Q. WHY IS MYSTIQUE PLAYING STRYKER AT THE END OF THE FILM?***
>
> **Kinsberg** : *“I wanted Wolverine to end up with Stryker at the end of the film, but
> when we got down the line on that, it felt like such a downer ending,
> and there wasn’t any ripple in time. It was the same – the location
> where Stryker grabbed Logan was different, but Logan’s fate was very
> much the same. I felt like we hadn’t made enough of a ripple.*
>
> *“So from there we thought about who else it could be. I was thinking
> of having other people on the boat – he could be fished out by Charles
> and Hank – but **we set this thing up where Mystique is masquerading as
> a military character saving mutants from going into some sort of
> experimental programme in Saigon early on**, so there’s a really nice
> symmetry there at the end.”*

And in [this interview](http://www.scifinow.co.uk/news/x-men-days-of-future-past-ending-explained-spoilers/) with ScifiNow

> It’s a neat little handwave, because there’s still loads of things we
> don’t know – like how Logan ended up in the Weapon-X project and got
> his Adamantium skeleton **if he was being led away by
> Mystique-as-Stryker and not Stryker himself.**