# Why does Raven rescue Logan?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, marvel

So, I just watched *Days of Future Past* and I'm trying to understand something. During the film, Logan and Raven have only one<sup>a</sup> direct interaction together: the fight in Paris where Trask was attempting to sell his Sentinels to the communist nations. Raven pretty much misses any interaction with Logan while he's fighting Magneto at the White House because she's already inside of the secure bunker and Magneto ends the fight with Logan prior to breaking the bunker open.

Even after Raven saves the President, Cabinet, and by extension, Trask, there's no dialog or other information we're privy to that indicates Raven should know Logan is even in the area, let alone stuck with steel rebar and drowning at the bottom of the Chesapeake Bay.

So, this leads to two questions: how does Raven discover Logan is in the bay and why does she bother rescuing him?

---

<sup>a</sup>: There's a deleted scene where Charles, Logan, Hank, and Raven talk about the consequences of Raven's actions at length. IMO, this scene would help a lot towards explaining Raven's actions at the very end of the movie. But deleted scenes aren't canon, right? And this wouldn't really help explain how Raven even knows Logan is in the bay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this character being impersonated?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59246/is-this-character-being-impersonated)

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy Mind pointing out where that question answers my question? So far, I haven't found a single satisfactory answer and I already know Raven is impersonating Stryker.

Comment: Voted to leave open because while one of the answers there (Valorum's) somewhat answers the "why the rescue", there's indeed no explanation as to the "how she knew Logan was there" (except for handwaving)

Comment: well, if it's in the extended edition and not "just" a deleted scene, then I'd consider it canon, much like everything from LotR extended edition is canon and just not included in the shorter version told to people who don't have long enough attention spans / attention for details ;)

Answer (score 3):

> how does Raven discover Logan is in the bay and why does she bother rescuing him?

It’s quite possible this happens by coincidence.

When Logan is being lifted from the water, we see that Raven has taken on the appearance of William Stryker, and is on the boat that’s retrieving Logan.

She could have taken on Stryker’s appearance as a way to avoid capture, and keep an eye on the military’s activity around mutants. The boat could already have been retrieving Logan, based on the military spotting an apparent mutant being several hundred metres into the water; Raven may have only been on the boat because she looked like Stryker.

Comment: I agree, that's quite possible. But if that is indeed the reason, that's pretty underwhelming. I take it we don't know why Raven impersonated Stryker then.

Comment: @Ellesedil: “I take it we don't know why Raven impersonated Stryker then” — as I say, presumably to avoid capture, and to enable her to keep an eye on what the military was doing with mutants, just like she’s doing at the start of the film. I agree that it’s not particularly obvious what we’re meant to glean from the scene, although maybe there’s an implication that Mystique won’t particularly act in Logan’s best interests. We kind of see where Logan ends up in *Apocalypse*, although we don’t discover what involvement, if any, Mystique had in that.